# 50 Questions per 30 days is fine. Does that mean I have to move to another forum?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, rate-limiting

He he he he... Yea I am guilty here. I shouldn't have asked that many questions. That's what happens when my partner wants me to program in Objective-C, a language I don't know. Well, I improved a lot in these 30 days.

Definitely! I know I am guilty. I am not complaining about rules at all. In fact, if it's not because of that rule, I wouldn't have found out about this.

But think about it, more visitors, more advertising revenue for Stack Overflow.

This will drive them out.

Don't worry, Stack Overflow is the best out there and I'll come back when I am within my limit again. But seriously, unless a person's question quality sucks so much, this will effectively force them to find something else.

By the way, is this limit per account or IP? Imagine if I have plenty of programmers and each of them want to ask questions.

And finally, what would be a good place to ask Objective-C questions? I don't think this question take away visitors from Stack Overflow. It's Stack Overflow's own limit that does.

Comment: I would think your time would have been better spent reading one of the many fine tutorials or books about Objective C before beginning to post questions. :) Learning a new language by moderate-latency question asking sounds horrible to me.

Comment: If they were 50 well researched questions I'd be all for it. Most are marginal at best with little future value to the community.

Comment: This post epitomizes your flawed views.   You come across as self-important.  more visitors more revenue?  Not when visitors do not come back due to a deluge of subpar questions, not to mention the attitudes displayed in your comments, etc.  Old thread I know.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This limit is by IP (for new users) and account.

We ask that you please be respectful of others' time and not saturate the site with dozens or hundreds of questions per day.

If this is a rule you find onerous -- if you "need" to ask more than 50 questions per month -- we encourage you to find other places on the internet to ask.

Comment: It's okay. Just asking. I am not asking hundreds. I did ask more than 50. I saw that some of my questions are bad. Also I am online when most people are asleep in US. What do you mean by IP (for new users). Why you put (for new users) after IP? Say my employee used to work on his own home. But then he sign in on my office and ask question. Does that count?

Comment: Also, would the time used to post 50 questions per month be better used elsewhere?

Answer (score 19):

You have a habit of asking questions that are extremely similar to each other several times in a row:

- [How can we detect touch up or click events in textview in IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067517/how-can-we-detect-touch-up-or-click-events-in-textview-in-iphone)
- [Capturing Touch Up Event in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040399/capturing-touch-up-event-in-textview)

---

- [Can Text Fields Auto-Recognize Phone Numbers and Links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053778/can-text-fields-auto-recognize-phone-numbers-and-links)
- [UITextView setting to detect phone numbers and hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067484/uitextview-setting-to-detect-phone-numbers-and-hyperlinks)

---

- [What happen when we inherits one entity from another entity in core data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166958/what-happen-when-we-inherits-one-entity-from-another-entity-in-core-data)
- [Multiple Relationship In Core Data to Entities of the Same Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150819/multiple-relationship-in-core-data-to-entities-of-the-same-type)

---

- [Can iMac use CLLocationManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188821/can-imac-use-cllocationmanager)
- [Location Manager with iMac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168660/location-manager-with-imac)
- [Where is _kCLLocationAccuracyBest defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168672/where-is-kcllocationaccuracybest-defined)

---

- [What's the difference between .xcdatamodeld and BadgerNew.xcdatamodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827662/whats-the-difference-between-xcdatamodeld-and-badgernew-xcdatamodel)
- [How to Turn xcdatamodel file into xcdatamodeld file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850401/how-to-turn-xcdatamodel-file-into-xcdatamodeld-file)

---

- [How to "Turn On" Version Editor in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815427/how-to-turn-on-version-editor-in-xcode-4)
- [How to "Version" Your Xcode Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660016/how-to-version-your-xcode-code)

---

- [How do you watch or evaluate an expression in xcode like visual studio's immediate window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662629/how-to-watch-expression-in-xcode)
- [Watch Expression in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779302/watch-expression-in-xcode)

---

- [How to display "the" Assistant Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624972/how-to-display-the-assistant-editor)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624487/where-is-the-assistant-editor-in-interface-builder

I think that these probably contributed to your hitting the question cap. I've also seen a fair number of questions from you that I believe you could *easily* have answered by doing a simple doc or SO search. In my view, your questions have not been particularly useful or clear, nor have they shown much research effort (criteria from the voting tooltips).

I hope you'll take this into consideration when you are able to ask questions again.

Comment: Definitely! I know I am guilty. I am not complaining about rules at all. In fact, if it's not because of that rule, I wouldn't have found out about this.

Comment: I like that they are so many links that you soon had to stop replacing the link text with the question text because it was taking too long

Comment: @Kop: That formatting actually is done, and stops, automatically. I can't remember if it's a "won't-fix" or "by-design", but I've seen a question about it here on Meta. But you're right that it would have taken me more time than I wanted to spend to work around that.

Answer (score 1):

You can clearly ask good questions and people clearly want to answer your questions.  The site needs good questions and so when your time limit is up please **come back and give us your best questions**.

Now that you know about the limit, just try to answer some of your easier questions by yourself and save the harder ones for Stack Overflow.  If you only ask the questions that you are truly stuck on, the limit of fifty questions per thirty days will seem like a virtually unreachable ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could ask more questions in that period if you answered some (e.g. you might be able to somehow gain some more question credit by giving back to the community you are taking from). Surely that much active development and learning in Objective-C would mean you could begin answering some questions other Objective-C users are asking...or answer questions in areas you already have a good understanding.

Likely, if you were giving back to the community (you currently have zero answers) you might have some leniency...

Comment: I won't get more limit but I will give back to the community. I love you all. It's just that all this downvote on this question get on my nerve :(

Comment: @Jim Thio, you may well be able to prove you need more or change the system if you could validly ask 50 questions and also be answering just as much...