# Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, error-message

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [50 question per month limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit)

I have asked only two questions till today. Why is it showing this error message? Please help, I would like to know the reason behind it.

Comment: See also [50 question per month limit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit) - I was under the assumption that this limit is implemented per IP too; so a proxy and fellow users would count into it. (Can't find this mentioned however.)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93481/148103 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111481/why-am-i-hitting-a-question-rate-limit-when-i-havent-posted-all-day

Comment: Do you share a workplace/computer with any other SE users? It's odd, you have only asked two questions (not counting deleted/quality-filtered accounts).

Comment: @tomb: no ,i enquired them none used my computer

Comment: @Muhsin - it's not your computer that's important but your internet connection. Are you accessing Stack Overflow at work? If so then you and all your colleagues who use the site as well will share the same IP address - that of your company.

Comment: @chris: ya ... i m using Stack overflow in my office only that may be the prob.but when my officemate  posted a question just now it didnt any error message like that ,his question was posted .he has more rep than me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of other users who frequently share your IP address. Two of them have asked quite a lot of questions in the last month.

You might want to have a talk with co-workers / roommates about chilling out on the question asking a bit.

Comment: and one of them has at least 8 accounts (mostly thrown away after asking one question)

Comment: @shog : can able to know user's name ??

Comment: @shog and marc: can i able know users??

Comment: @Muhsin: No.  You'll have to figure that out on your own.

Comment: many guys it may due to that i am  using Stack overflow in my office .but when my officemate posted a question . it didnt any error message like that ,his question was posted .he has more rep than me .wat may be the reason

Comment: *"You might want to have a talk with co-workers / roommates about chilling out on the question asking a bit."* - Hugh? Why are you making this the asker's responsibility??? Are you going to blame them for Kennedy's assassination next?

Comment: Because, while they might not see managing their network as their responsibility, it certainly isn't mine @jww. As for Kennedy... they know what they did.